# Canvas and LWUIT in J2ME

Tags: canvas, java-me, lwuit

In my application I have to add `TextField`,`Label` and `Button` in the Tab View of the Canvas Class.

How can I add LWUIT components into Canvas Class?

Comment: @casperOne It's not "difficult to tell what is being asked here", see eg [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11683017/839601). If you have trouble understanding it (both question and answer), consider finding someone with [lwuit](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/lwuit/info "what is this?") knowledge to explain

Comment: @gnat No explaination needed and no reason to find someone with lwuit knowledge (your snark is not appreciated, remember, [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#benice)).  There's no original research effort.  This is closed as NARQ on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @casperOne if the OP edits the question with the code snippet from their app, would that qualify as a proof of research effort?

Comment: @gnat The code snippet in itself is not proof of research effort, it just shows code from their app.  If there's code which shows "oh, I did this here, it didn't work/produce the results I wanted" that's a better indicator of research effort.  It depends on whether or not the person has actual code showing what they've done as opposed to a blank space in their code with a comment that says "do something here".

Comment: @casperOne hm that sounds like _elevated standard_ compared to vast majority of SO questions I see. Okay since this question has been apparently flagged for your attention, it probably deserves stricter judgement

Comment: @gnat It's actually not an elevated standard, it's the *norm*.  It's just a matter of thousands of new questions a day, millions already on the site, and 10K users + 15 mods to handle the quality on all of them.  It's a fairly uphill battle.  But when we see them, we handle them pretty much all the same.  There's just a lot we *don't* see.

Comment: @casperOne fair enough, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can solve this building the `Form` in this way.

It seems that you want to have a TabView on the top of your `Form`.To do that, you can use a `Form` with a `BorderLayout` and put the `Label`,`TextField` and the `Button` inside a `Container` and set this `Container`to the `NORTH`position of the `BorderLayout`. It will be close to be a `TabView`